# Создание функции для части кода

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

В данном хендлере:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='call')
async def answer(call: CallbackQuery):
    connect = sqlite3.connect('main.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT grup FROM Users WHERE id = ?', (call.from_user.id,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        print('none')
    for row in result:
        if row == '1':
            cursor.execute("SELECT `Tab` FROM `Spisok` WHERE `Par` = 'rez'")
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            await call.message.answer(row[0])
```

Имею вот такое начало. которое повторяется во всех других хендрерах. Как эту часть кода сделать отдельной функцией, и не писать в каждом хендлере ?

```
async def answer(call: CallbackQuery):
        connect = sqlite3.connect('main.db')
        cursor = connect.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT grup FROM Users WHERE id = ?', (call.from_user.id,))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result is None:
            print('none')
        for row in result:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте `contextmanager`:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def get_user(call: CallbackQuery):
    connect = sqlite3.connect('main.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT grup FROM Users WHERE id = ?', (call.from_user.id,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        print('none')
    else:
        for row in result:
            yield row

@dp.callback_query_handler(text='call')
async def answer(call: CallbackQuery):
    with get_user(call) as row:
        if row == '1':
            cursor.execute("SELECT `Tab` FROM `Spisok` WHERE `Par` = 'rez'")
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            await call.message.answer(row[0])
```